# php mysql multiple loops for remaining rows

Tags: php, mysql

I need to print 5 title from my content table into two html `<div>`. first, I print 2 title using php loops with `LIMIT 2`:

```
$SQL = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . CONTENT . " WHERE active = ?, ORDER BY name LIMIT 2", 'YES');

  foreach($SQL AS $row){

  ?>

    <div class="levelOne"><?PHP echo $row['title']; ?></div>

  <?PHP

  }

  ?>
```

output:

```
TITLE 1

TITLE 5
```

Now I need to print 3 remaining title using php loops with `LIMIT 3`:

```
 $SQL = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . CONTENT . " WHERE active = ?, ORDER BY name LIMIT 3", 'YES');

  foreach($SQL AS $row){

  ?>

    <div class="levelTwo"><?PHP echo $row['title']; ?></div>

  <?PHP

  }

  ?>
```

output:

```
TITLE 1

TITLE 5

TITLE 7
```

This output is false(because title 1 and 5 is in first output So my second code is wrong).Now, Ho do print 3 remaining title like this output:

```
 TITLE 7

 TITLE 9

 TITLE 11
```

Comment: One way to do it is to use `LIMIT 2,3` on the second query. The first argument is the number of rows to skip, the next argument is the maximum number of rows to return. In this example, skip the first two rows, then return the next three rows.

Comment: @spencer7593: My way is true and good? Or Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change sql code as follow

SELECT * FROM " . CONTENT . " WHERE active = ?, ORDER BY name LIMIT 2,5

It will return your value from 2-5.